# How do I upgrade Guix?

Tags: package-management, gnu

Guix 1.0.0 was released recently. I have an old version that I installed once and did not use for a long time, so I decided to try 1.0.0.

```
$ guix --version
guix (GNU Guix) 0.16.0
Copyright (C) 2018 the Guix authors
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

But it seems that I cannot upgrade it. I tried `guix pull` and also `guix package -u guix`, but then, when I run `guix --version` again, I get the same `0.16.0` version.

I also tried running the installation script again, but it finds the old version and refuses to overwrite.

(I'm using the Guix package manager on a Debian system)

What would be the proper way to upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

You should not have the `guix` package installed, so `guix package -u guix` is not the right way to upgrade.  The `guix` package available through Guix will *always* be older than the version of Guix you use to install it.

`guix pull` is the correct way to upgrade. By default `guix pull` installs the latest version of Guix to the profile `~/.config/guix/current`, so you need to ensure that `~/.config/guix/current/bin` comes first in your PATH variable.